# Foundation 4: Where is the global foundaton settings partial that gets imported on the first line of app.scss, and why should it be first?

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm confused by this. Wouldn't all the following imports just override whatever was in this global settings partial anyway?

The comment reads simply `// Global Foundation Settings`. Looking at older documentation the comment was different and made more sense: `// You custom settings file to override Foundation defaults` http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/3.2.5/sass.php

Shouldn't a global settings file which overrides Foundation's settings be imported *last*?

Comment: I agree and it's not explained in the docs. The main problem is using front end packet managers like bower, can't really have this asset  in bower since you have to override main package.